# Does "sendmsg" free memory of the buffer or msg?

Tags: c, linux, memory

Does `sendmsg` free memory of the buffer or msg?

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense!

Comment: You're going to have to read the documentation.

Comment: Do you have any code to go along with what you are attempting?

Comment: Read the man pages, Google **AND searh SO**. Just like what I found [here].(http://stackoverflow.com/a/4259888/1272394)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `sendmsg()` does not free the passed-in memory.  It cannot possibly do so, because that memory may not even have come from `malloc()`.  You can `free()` the memory any time after calling `sendmsg()`, as the system will have already made the necessary copies.

Comment: For some reason I find the line "... that memory may not even have come from malloc()" humorous.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do free it. It just sends out bytes of memory making using of `msghdr` structure.

Usually you allocate memory write into iovec of `msghdr` and call sendmsg to transfer it as,

```
char buffer[SIZE]="DATA";  // Data to send into buffer
struct iovec io;           // Segment which will store outgoing message
struct msghdr msgh;        // msghdr structure 
...
io.iov_base = buffer;      // Specify the components of the message in an iovec
io.iov_len = SIZE;
msgh.msg_iov = &io;  
... 
sendmsg(fd,&msgh,0);       // send msg which just send msg in a iovec buffer
```

Comment: Thanks. i got it now. thanks again.