# What sendmsg() function internally does?

Tags: c

I want to know how the kernel fill the ip header using this `sendmsg()` function.

`sendmsg()` function is used for send the messages in connection less
via socket. We pass 3 arguments to this function. They are,file descriptor,
msghdr structure, flags.

In `msghdr` structure i give the destination ip to send the packets. In here,
for every packet is send via ethernet card, we definitely fill the 
headers based on the OSI layers. So using `sendmsg()` function, how the kernel take the ip specified in the `msghdr` structure and fill that ip
to ip header to send data to destination system ?

Can anyone give a clear explanation for this question ?

Comment: Please specify at least *which* operating system's kernel you're talking about ...

Comment: I'm not use what you mean by "fill that ip to ip header"? Do you mean how the kernel figures out which interface it should send the packet through? How it create the actual [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_header)? Something else? Please elaborate.

Comment: _send via ethernet card_: it depends on the destination address

Comment: If you want to digging into linux sources take a look at [Linux/net/socket.c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258834/how-sendmsg-works) and staring from line 1987 you can see what happen with parameters. [This SO post could also be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258834/how-sendmsg-works)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you have specified the dest IP already. The source IP is picked by linux kernel from the interface the packet is sent out on. his can change based on if the application has called "bind" on a certain interface.